Azure Open AI Embedding Skill
I created the following skill set in Azure AI Search:
{
  "@odata.context": "https://srch-tender-prod-weu-001.search.windows.net/$metadata#skillsets/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DC7350076C5133\"",
  "name": "standalone-skillset",
  "description": "Skillset to chunk documents and generating embeddings",
  "skills": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SplitSkill",
      "name": "#1",
      "description": "Split skill to chunk documents",
      "context": "/document",
      "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
      "textSplitMode": "pages",
      "maximumPageLength": 5000,
      "pageOverlapLength": 0,
      "maximumPagesToTake": 0,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/content"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "textItems",
          "targetName": "pages"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.AzureOpenAIEmbeddingSkill",
      "name": "#2",
      "description": "Skill to generate embeddings via Azure OpenAI",
      "context": "/document/pages/*",
      "resourceUri": "https://oai-tender-prod-swec-001.openai.azure.com",
      "apiKey": "<redacted>",
      "deploymentId": "text-ada-002-embedding",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/pages/*"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "embedding",
          "targetName": "vector"
        }
      ],
      "authIdentity": null
    }
  ],
  "cognitiveServices": null,
  "knowledgeStore": null,
  "indexProjections": {
    "selectors": [
      {
        "targetIndexName": "standalone",
        "parentKeyFieldName": "parent_id",
        "sourceContext": "/document/pages/*",
        "mappings": [
          {
            "name": "chunk",
            "source": "/document/pages/*",
            "sourceContext": null,
            "inputs": []
          },
          {
            "name": "vector",
            "source": "/document/pages/*/vector",
            "sourceContext": null,
            "inputs": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "parameters": {
      "projectionMode": "skipIndexingParentDocuments"
    }
  },
  "encryptionKey": null
}

The Azure Open AI resource has the following endpoint: (https://i.sstatic.net/0kicDALC.png)
The index looks like this: https://i.sstatic.net/Cb5oMkDr.png, https://i.sstatic.net/pzqhiWNf.png and https://i.sstatic.net/gVthtbIz.png
The indexer looks like this: https://i.sstatic.net/2fZciOIM.png
However, this skill set gives an error when executing the indexer for this skill set: The remote name could not be resolved: 'oai-tender-prod-swec-001.openai.azure.com'
(https://i.sstatic.net/yrA2W90w.png)
What is the reason for this?

You should have used the endpoint in screenshot 1.

When setting "resourceUri": "https://swedencentral.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/" I get the following error: One or more skills are invalid. Details: Error in skill '#2': Invalid resourceUri. Provide a valid resourceUri for the Azure Open AI service.

@Luuk van Gasteren share the indexes and Indexers also

@Sampath, I shared the indexes and indexers above

The API you have given in the screenshot is based on region; it doesn't support Azure AI search. Therefore, you must provide the OpenAI resource URI, which ends like this:
https://<Your_url_name>.openai.azure.com/

I also encountered the same error when providing an incorrect OpenAI resource name.

Check your resource name, oai-tender-prod-swec-001, which is incorrect in your case.

I have the following OpenAI configuration: https://i.sstatic.net/gBCxiYIz.png.
This endpoint is based on the region the OpenAI resource is in and not on the resource (name) itself. Can this be changed or configured when setting up the OpenAI resource?

No. Region based endpoint doesn't works. You have to give endpoint as mentioned in the solution

In the code of the skills above you see that I use "resourceUri": "https://oai-tender-prod-swec-001.openai.azure.com" in the embedding skill, which is resource based. However, this is not stated as an endpoint in the OpenAI resource

In  my solution 1st screen shot shows where the endpoint will be and also this error comes when you give wrong resource url or it doesn't exits. Please add you resource group screen shot as shown in my solution
